# Does the PSP Store use a DRM system?

Tags: digital-distribution, drm, psp

I bought a few games from the PSP store but I'd like to know if they are bound to my account or to my device.

In other words: if my PSP is gone for good, will I be able to download my games again on a new PSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purchases on PSN Store are tied to you PSN account. You can re-download things already purchased.